# Magically, you can not view the image

Tags: html, image

I have maybe simple problem but I really don't know what's wrong :(

http://airbyt.cz/byty Images in the divs are not loaded in all browsers except google chrome and chrome mobile. It doesn't log error in the path.

there is code.

```
<main>
<div class="object-byt"><h1>Modern apartment close to center with jacuzzi</h1><div class="for-img"><div class="zakryj"></div><span><a href="https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/15704845" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span><img src="img/ap-1.jpg" alt="interior"></div></div>
<div class="object-byt"><h1 class="broken">Cozy apartment in Prague</h1><div class="for-img"><div class="zakryj"></div><span><a href="https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/5974283" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span><img src="img/ap-2.jpg" alt="interior"></div></div>
<div class="object-byt"><h1>Super luxury apartment in center of Prague</h1><div class="for-img"><div class="zakryj"></div><span><a href="https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/16286264" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span><img src="img/ap-3.jpg" alt="interior"></div></div>
<div class="object-byt"><h1>Great apartment in center of Prague</h1><div class="for-img"><div class="zakryj"></div><span><a href="https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/11766068" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span><img src="img/ap-4.jpg" alt="interior"></div></div>
<div class="object-byt"><h1 class="broken">Cozy apartment in heart of Prague</h1><div class="for-img"><div class="zakryj"></div><span><a href="https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/5290902" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span><img src="img/ap-5.jpg" alt="interior"></div></div>        
</main>
```

I will be glad for every advice. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is in webp format which is only read by Chrome. You need to convert it to a regular image file. I tried http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg on one of your images and it worked. I'm sure there are many other solutions as well.